# Change Title bar icon Kibana 5

Tags: analytics, visualization, elastic-stack, kibana-5

Could someone help on how I would like to put a custom title bar on Kibana 5. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution: 
For the word Kibana, go to \src\ui\views\Chrome.jade then modify line 12
For the pink icon I replaced with my own at \src\ui\public\assets\favicons\favicon.ico